# Is there a way to find the nᵗʰ entry in itertools.combinations() without converting the entire thing to a list?

Tags: python, list, iteration, combinations, python-itertools

I am using the `itertools` library module in python.

I am interested the different ways to choose 15 of the first 26000 positive integers. The function `itertools.combinations(range(1,26000), 15)` enumerates all of these possible subsets, in a lexicographical ordering.

The [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) 26000 choose 15 is a very large number, on the order of 10^54. However, python has no problem running the code `y = itertools.combinations(range(1,26000), 15)` as shown in the sixth line below.

[image: itertools memory error when converting to list]

If I try to do `y[3]` to find just the 3rd entry, I get a TypeError. This means I need to convert it into a list first.  The problem is that trying to convert it into a list gives a MemoryError. All of this is shown in the screenshot above.

---

Converting it into a list *does* work for smaller combinations, like 6 choose 3, shown below.

[image: successful conversion of small example to list]

---

My question is:

**Is there a way to access specific elements in `itertools.combinations()` without converting it into a list?**

I want to be able to access, say, the first 10000 of these ~10^54 enumerated 15-element subsets.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generator expression:

```
comb = itertools.combinations(range(1,26000), 15)
comb1000 = (next(comb) for i in range(1000))
```

To jump directly to the *nth* combination, here is an [itertools recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
def nth_combination(iterable, r, index):
    """Equivalent to list(combinations(iterable, r))[index]"""
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r < 0 or r > n:
        raise ValueError
    c = 1
    k = min(r, n-r)
    for i in range(1, k+1):
        c = c * (n - k + i) // i
    if index < 0:
        index += c
    if index < 0 or index >= c:
        raise IndexError
    result = []
    while r:
        c, n, r = c*r//n, n-1, r-1
        while index >= c:
            index -= c
            c, n = c*(n-r)//n, n-1
        result.append(pool[-1-n])
    return tuple(result)
```

It's also available in `more_itertools.nth_combination`

```
>>> import more_itertools  # pip install more-itertools
>>> more_itertools.nth_combination(range(1,26000), 15, 123456)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 18, 19541)
```

To instantly "fast-forward" a combinations instance to this position and continue iterating, you can set the state to the *previously* yielded state (note: 0-based state vector) and continue from there:

```
>>> comb = itertools.combinations(range(1,26000), 15)   
>>> comb.__setstate__((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 17, 19540))
>>> next(comb)  
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 18, 19542)
```

Comment: I've never seen this before! +1 How does it work? This looks like magic to me :)

Comment: If I modified it to make it ```comb10000 = (next(comb) for i in range(23230000, 23240000))```, would that work? I suspect it would just give me the first 10000 and not the middle, but I could be wrong ...

Comment: Yeah, it will give you just the first 10,000.  But I do have a way to fast-forward this iterator to arbitrary position in O(1) time and space, I'll edit the question to demonstrate.

Comment: Do you think I should ask a separate question for fast-forwarding the iterator to an arbitrary position? Or edit this question? I'm mostly on math.SE so I'm not very familiar with the etiquette on this one ...

Comment: Hmm, it's bordeline but I think in this case it's okay to edit the question. That's already very similar to what you asked originally, except you'd like a shortcut without having to "consume" all the combinations that came before.

Comment: Does ```more_itertools.nth_combination``` have to generate all of the combinations before n as well? Edit: because if it does not, then that seems like by far the easiest way

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the *first* few elements, it's pretty straightforward with `islice`:

```
import itertools

print(list(itertools.islice(itertools.combinations(range(1,26000), 15), 1000)))
```

---

Note that `islice` internally iterates the combinations up to the specified point, so it can't magically give you the *middle* elements without iterating all the way there. You'd have to go down the route of computing the elements you want combinatorially in that case.

Comment: Hmm, so, from what I understand:  if I wanted elements 10001 to 20000, I could use ```islice```, but I'd have to make the full 1 to 20000 list, then remove the first 10000, which works, but doesn't scale well (it would be a bit of a pain if i wanted the elements from 10^50 to 10^50+10000). So for things in the middle I'd have to use a different method?

Comment: `islice` does that for you, so you would just do `islice(..., 10001, 20000)`. But if you did `islice(..., 10000000000, 10000000000+1000)` it would hang because it still has to generate (and discard) the first 10000000000 elements. The different method would be, in this case, writing the actual code to generate the 10000000000'th lexicographically-ordered combination - which requires some math.

Comment: Interesting ... that makes sense, thank you. One thing I don't yet understand: why is it that ```itertools.combinations(range(1,26000), 15)``` doesn't hang, but hangs when it's converted to a list? Does it not even generate the combinations until I try to convert it to a list?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it! `itertools.combinations` doesn't generate any combinations - it just promises to (it returns what is called a *generator*). When you use `list` it will generate *every* combination to place in the list.